# this is my realloc version, is it good ? any suggestion are welcomed

Tags: c

I am trying to recode some c functions myself.
This is an my implementation of **realloc** function, any updates or suggestion about how to improve it are welcomed.

```
void    *ft_realloc(void *old_ptr, size_t old_size, size_t size) {
    void *new_ptr;
    
    if (size == 0 && old_ptr != NULL)
    {
        free (old_ptr);
        return (NULL);
    }
    else if (old_ptr == NULL)
    {
        if (!(old_ptr = malloc (size)))
            return (NULL);
        ft_memset(old_ptr, 0, size);
        return (old_ptr);
    }
    else if (size >= old_size) {
        if (!(new_ptr = malloc (size)))
            return (NULL);
        ft_memset(new_ptr, 0, size);
        ft_strncpy (new_ptr, old_ptr, old_size);
        free (old_ptr);
        return (new_ptr);
    }
    else if (size < old_size)
    {
        if (!(new_ptr = malloc(size)))
            return (NULL);
        ft_memset(new_ptr, 0, size);
        ft_strncpy (new_ptr, old_ptr, size);
        free (old_ptr);
        return (new_ptr);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

`ft_memset` and `ft_strncpy` are just my implementation of `memset` and `strncpy` they behave the same way!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site. There isn't enough here to review. Rather than explaining what` ft_memset()` and `ft_strncpy()` are they should be included in the question. The rest of `ft_realloc()` depends a lot on the code using it so that should be included in the question as well.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. (`ft_strncpy` reads *erroneous* - think about embedded NULs.) `any [suggestion is] welcome` Tag [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]. Don't write, never present uncommented code. Reduce code multiplication.

Comment: @greybeard , Hello, you are write, i will try to comment my code next time. Thank you for the review.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    *ft_realloc(void *old_ptr, size_t old_size, size_t size) {
    if (size == 0 && old_ptr != NULL)
    {
        free (old_ptr);
    }
    else if (old_ptr == NULL)
    {
        if (old_ptr = malloc(size))
        {
            ft_memset(old_ptr, 0, size);
            return (old_ptr);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        void *new_ptr;
        if (new_ptr = malloc(size))
        {
            ft_memset(new_ptr, 0, size);
            
            if (size >= old_size)
                ft_strncpy (new_ptr, old_ptr, old_size);
            else
                ft_strncpy (new_ptr, old_ptr, size);
            
            free (old_ptr);
            return (new_ptr);
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

My insightful observation: OP's code has redundancies.
My answer: I removed some redundancies, which makes the code possible faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This answer doesn't really offer much for the OP. Please (re-) read [The help center page _How do I write a good answer?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Note it states: "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"

Comment: Thank you for your time, indeed i had some redundancies to eliminate, thank you very much !

Comment: `&& old_ptr != NULL` not needed.  Just free when `size == 0`.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: `ft_strncpy` is very likely wrong - there is nothing in `realloc()` involving _strings_.   `ft_memcpy()` would make more sense.

Comment: `ft_memset(new_ptr, 0, size);` is wasteful.  Better only zero memory beyond the former size - if at all as `realloc()` does not do that.

Comment: An alternative to `if (old_ptr = malloc(size)) { ft_memset(old_ptr, 0, size); return (old_ptr); }` would be `return calloc(1, size);`